# Toggle field with jquery and woocommerce function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a input like this on my first page `<input type="number" id="people" name="ppl" min="1" class="uniform-input number" value="7" required="">`

I wanted to use the value to toggle some fields on the woocommerce checkout. I want to show 2 name fields when the input value="2" and so on. But the code deletes all the custom fields. I don't know if I classed and targeted the div correctly Does anyone know what the problem is?

header.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      toggleFields();
      $("#people").on("keyup change", function () {
    toggleFields();
      });
    });


    function toggleFields() {
      $("#personen1, #personen2, #personen3, #personen4, #personen5, #personen6, #personen7, #personen8").hide();
      if ($("#people").val() < 9)
    $("#personen" + $("#people").val()).show();
    }
</script>
```

functions.php

```
function wordimpress_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

 //Check if Book in Cart (UPDATE WITH YOUR PRODUCT ID)
 $book_in_cart = wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( 759 );

 //Book is in cart so show additional fields
 if ( $book_in_cart === true ) {
 echo '<div class="container" id="personen1"><div class="jumbotron"><h2 style="color:red;">' . __( 'Buchungsinformationen' ) . '</h2>';

 woocommerce_form_field( 'person1_name', array(
 'type'  => 'text',
 'class' => array( 'person1 form-row-wide' ),
 'placeholder' => 'Vorname und Nachname eingeben',
 'label' => __( '1. Person' ),
 ), $checkout->get_value( 'person1_name' ) );

 echo '</div>';


 echo '<div class="container" id="personen2"><div class="jumbotron">';

 woocommerce_form_field( 'person1_name', array(
 'type'  => 'text',
 'class' => array( 'person1 form-row-wide' ),
 'placeholder' => 'Vorname und Nachname eingeben',
 'label' => __( '1. Person' ),
 ), $checkout->get_value( 'person1_name' ) );


  woocommerce_form_field( 'person2_name', array(
 'type'  => 'text',
 'class' => array( 'person2 form-row-wide' ),
 'placeholder' => 'Vorname und Nachname eingeben',
 'label' => __( '2. Person' ),
 ), $checkout->get_value( 'person2_name' ) );

 echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `does not work somehow` ? what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: @dreamweiver I want to show 2 name fields when the input value="2" and so on. But the code above deletes all the fields. I don't know if i classed and targeted the div correctly.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, with your jquery code & generated html DOM structure. http://www.jsfiddle.net